# WebGL: Int32/Uint32 rendertarget/texture

Tags: webgl

I am wondering is there any way to draw Int32/Uint32 into render target/texture? Also is it possible to upload Int32/Uint32 buffer with texImage2D without converting it to Float32? Does WebGL 1.0 have any such extension? Is going WebGL 2.0 to have such feature?